# How to style a page in wordpress?

Tags: css

I have the following code in css, I know how to assign different styling to div's but I want to add different styling in css only, is this possible?

The website is in wordpress, here's the link:

http://thinkstudio.co.za/canconsulting/presentation-design-gallery/

```
.gallery-filter a {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fb6334;
    padding: 3px 9px;
    margin: 4px 8px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 230ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 230ms linear;
    transition: background-color 230ms linear;
}


.gallery-filter a:hover, .gallery-filter .active {
    background-color:#09b7f8;
}
```

Comment: `I know how to assign different styling to div's but I want to add different styling in css only` What are you talking about ? If you know how to style your divs, then where's the problem ?

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Comment: dont worry ill consult google, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want to style anchors without using IDs.

CSS example: (:nth-child method)

```
.gallery-filter a:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
.gallery-filter a:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}
.gallery-filter a:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue;
}
.gallery-filter a:nth-child(4) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yauZr/

Comment: YES that is what I want to do... thank you SOOOOO much!!!!!!! you made my day!!!!

Comment: np, I'm glad I could help. When you'r happy with the answer, check the green mark (accept the answer). ;)